# In deriving the expression for mean square velocity of gas molecules why the integration is not taken from negative infinity to infinity?

Tags: kinetic-theory

Mean square velocity= $ C_{rms} =  \frac{\int_0^\infty C^2  dn}{n} $ ( where dn= no. density of molecules having velocity between C and C+dC , n= no. density of molecules including all velocities) .
Why is the integration taken from 0 to $\infty$ and not from $-\infty$ to $\infty$? The result will be twice as expected if the latter is taken.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. The integral must be from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ since the velocitities $(v_x, v_y, v_z)$ in this case is a random vector. Then you must integrate in its full range, to calculate expected values and probabilities. If you integrate only from $0$ to $\infty$ of $(v_x, v_y, v_z)$ you will get only half of the correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's a radial coordinate in spherical coordinates, and those go from $0 \to \infty.$

## Backstory

As you probably already know if you're asking this question, when we consider a small system which is able to exchange energy with a large one, the small subsystem equilibrates to the temperature of the large subsystem in order to maximize total entropy. When this happens, it turns out that the probabilities of macrostates of the small system have probabilities described by Boltzmann factors, $$ p(E) \propto e^{-E/k_\text B T}.$$For, say, an ideal gas, the only energy to consider is the kinetic energy of the particles, $$E = \sum_i \frac12 m_i v_i^2,$$ and since this is a continuous energy spectrum, we have to describe it in terms of a probability density: not $p(E)$ per se but $f(E)~dE$ being the probability that the system has energy between $E$ and $E + dE.$ Nevertheless we must enforce the above requirement by $f(E) \propto \exp(-E/k_\text B T).$

Now since our particles are not interacting we can just imagine that we're talking about the one-particle ideal gas, so we only have three velocity variables $v_x, v_y, v_z$ to deal with, and in terms of this any other average of any other quantity is going to be $$\big\langle g(v_x, v_y, v_z) \big\rangle = \frac{\iiint_{\mathbb R^3} dv_x~dv_y~dv_z ~g(v_x, v_y, v_z)~e^{- m (v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2)/2k_\text B T}}{\iiint_{\mathbb R^3} dv_x~dv_y~dv_z ~e^{- m (v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2)/2k_\text B T}}.$$
The bottom is just the normalization factor forcing $g=1$ to have average $\langle 1 \rangle = 1,$ the top contains the thing that we're averaging as well as the probability weight due to the Boltzmann factor, and that's it, and all of our three velocity components range over velocity-space from $-\infty$ to $+\infty.$

## Spherical coordinates

Now if we want to know the average velocity we're talking about $g = \sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2}$ and then it is very helpful to instead think in terms of the spherical coordinates of this space: $v, \theta, \phi.$ The $\theta, \phi$ specify the direction of the corresponding velocity vector, the $v$ specifies its magnitude as a radial component. For any $g$ with no true angular dependence $g = g(v)$ the above expression reduces to:$$\big\langle g(v) \big\rangle = \frac{\int_0^\infty 4\pi v^2~dv~g(v)~e^{- m v^2/2k_\text B T}}{\int_0^\infty 4\pi v^2~dv~e^{-m v^2/2 k_\text B T}}.$$We can then solve the denominator by the standard methods for Gaussian integrals, finding $\int_0^\infty dx~x^2~\exp(-a x^2) = \frac14 ~ \sqrt\pi ~ a^{-3/2},$ so multiplying by $4\pi$ gives $(\pi/a)^{3/2}$ and thus we get a prefactor of $(a/\pi)^{3/2}$ for the integral, making this into $$\big\langle g(v) \big\rangle = \left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_\text B T}\right)^{3/2} ~\int_0^\infty 4\pi v^2~dv~g(v)~e^{-m v^2/2 k_\text B T}.$$ For the mean speed, of course, $g(v) = v$ and the remainder of this integral is given by $\int_0^\infty dx~x^3~e^{-ax^2} = \frac 12 a^{-2},$ giving the answer $$\langle v \rangle = \left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_\text B T}\right)^{3/2} ~ 2\pi~\left(\frac{2 k_\text B T}{m}\right)^{2} = \sqrt{\frac{8 k_\text B T}{\pi m}}.$$

## Minor connecting details

One can of course view the above expression as a the probability of particles having speed between $v$ and $v+dv$ as being given by $f(v)~dv$ given by, $$f(v)~dv = \left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_\text B T}\right)^{3/2}~4\pi v^2~dv~g(v)~e^{-m v^2/2 k_\text B T},$$ and this is the famous [Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution). Furthermore if one integrates this one has a cumulative distribution function $F(v)$ and multiplying by the total number of particles $N$ in the subsystem, one has $n(v) = N~F(v)$ as the number of particles with speed less than $v$. The above expression can then be rewritten, $$\big\langle g(v)\big\rangle = \frac{1}N \int_0^\infty \frac{dn}{dv}~g(v)~dv = \frac{\int_{v:0\to\infty} g(v)~dn}{N}.$$ This is about as close as I can get to your expression, though please notice that $n$ actually goes from $0$ to $N$ and only $v$ goes from $0 \to \infty.$ Anyway, this is a minor detail because the key point in why $v$ does this is that $v$ is the radial coordinate for the spherical parameterization of the 3D $\{v_x, v_y, v_z\}$ space, which is why it ranges from 0 to $\infty.$

Comment: The radial coordinate gives the speed, right?But to prove that the mean square value of x component of c is the same as Newton's expression for speed of sound , we take integration from -infty to +infty. Why is it different here?

Comment: Because if you take $g(v_x, v_y, v_z) = v_x^n$ as the thing you want to average, you don't find it terribly useful to use spherical coordinates as that expression is not spherically symmetric. Instead you find yourself wanting to integrate out both the $dv_y$ and the $dv_z$ from both top and bottom integrals (they cancel perfectly) and focus only on the $v_x$ component, which now *is* a real number going from $-\infty$ to $+\infty.$

Answer (score 1):

The velocity is actually a vector $(v_x, v_y, v_z)$ and one is here interested in its length $C = \sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2}$, which is always positive. Since $dn$ is proportial to $dC$, the integration lower bound has to be 0.

If you were to look at the $v_x$ component only, then you would have a density of probability $P(v_x)$ to find that component between $v_x$ and $v_x+dv_x$, and to get the mean square of $v_x$ you would then compute $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} v_x^2 P(v_x) dv_x$. For $C$, there is another probability $Q(C)$, which can be computed from $P$, as you should have been taught, for the speed to be between $C$ and $C+dC$, and to get the mean square, you compute $\int_0^{+\infty} C^2 Q(C) dC$ (where of course $Q(C) dC = \frac{dn}{n}$ in your notations). You see that the same principle is at work but the domain of the variables $v_x$ and $C$ are different.

Comment: You mean we are integrating the speed? But to prove that the mean square value of x component of c is the same as Newton's expression for speed of sound , we take integration from -infty to +infty.

Comment: True. But different question, different answer.

Comment: The integration is actually over a number of molecules, not over the speed.

Comment: But why is the process different? Newtons expression only gives speed without any knowledge of its direction. @Luc J.Bourhis

Comment: Actually, dn= 4*pi*n*e^(-bc^2) * c^2 * dc . The integration is supposed to be over the speed. If it were over density then it will be from 0 to n. @fqq

Comment: Ok, yes, I was a bit puzzled by your formula actually!

Answer (score 0):

The expression you wrote provides speed and speed can not be in negative. So, the limit is from 0 to ∞.

Comment: But to prove that the mean square value of x component of c is the same as Newton's expression for speed of sound , we take integration from -infty to +infty. Why the process is changed for this?

Comment: I can't recognize what you are actually saying, can you please explain it further!